# mysqli bind_result and then get results using fetch() - not working inside a function

Tags: php, function, mysqli, fetch

Following 1st script work well and return multiple rows with the data. But when I tried to use this code in a function as shown in the 2nd script I cannot out put data, but it return the number of rows, I tried to use a return array() as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577678/mysqli-fetch-not-fetching) but still I cannot figure it out to work. Many thanks.

```
<?php
// 1st code
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare (" SELECT Name, City FROM user_db WHERE id = ? " ) ;
$stmt -> bind_param ('s', $id ) ;
$stmt -> execute () ;
$stmt -> store_result () ;
$stmt -> bind_result ( $name1, $city1  ) ;
while ( $stmt -> fetch () ) { echo $name1 .'-'. $city1  .'<br>' ; }
```

result of 1st code

```
name1-city1
name2-city2
name3-city3
```

2nd code - use 1st code in a function

```
function test ( $mysqli , $id ) {
    $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare (" SELECT Name, City FROM user_db WHERE id = ? " ) ;
    $stmt -> bind_param ('s', $id ) ;
    $stmt -> execute () ;
    $stmt -> store_result () ;
    $stmt -> bind_result ( $name, $city  ) ;
    return $stmt;
}

$stmt = test ( $mysqli , $id );

while ( $data = $stmt -> fetch () ) { 
    echo  $name .'-'. $city  .'<br>' ; 
}
```

result of 2nd code

```
-
-
-
```

Comment: those bound variables are out of scope, just put the fetching inside the function pushing inside an array, then make the return on that container

Comment: @Ghost , I do feel their is something to do with the return of the function, but I am not knowledgeable enough to understand it and do what you suggested, I m pretty new to the field, a small explanation with a little code will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bind_result after calling the function gave me the same result as in the first script, its a solution for what I was looking for, but still I do not understand why above 2nd script not working as expected

Call function

$stmt = test ( $mysqli , $id );

Then bind_result to the statement

$stmt -> bind_result ( $name, $city  ) ;

Answer (score 0):

For the goodness sake, use PDO

```
function test ( $db , $id ) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT Name, City FROM user_db WHERE id = ?") ;
    $stmt->execute([$id]);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}

$data = test ($pdo, $id);

foreach ($data as $row) { 
    echo  $row['Name'] .'-'. $row['City']  .'<br>' ; 
}
```

Comment: I am new and still not familiar with PDO. I known their are other ways to do this using mysqli, but I want to know why my code doesn't work inside the function ?

Comment: you've got your answer in the very first comment under the question.

Comment: And speaking of PDO, **you aren't familiar with mysqli as well**, are you? So why not to start learning the proper tool if you're only yet to start learning anyway?

Comment: Yeah I am new to mysqli as well and hoping to learn PDO, I am currently working on a small project and need to work this out. I do not really understand how to implement what is in the comments :-( , how can I use the results out side the function when I fetch it inside the function ? A little help will be very helpful

Comment: I don't see how you need any help given you've got your code working already

Comment: Ok, Sorry I thought what Ghost suggested is different from my solution

Comment: Well you can form an array in your function and return it. but I suppose this stuff is too complex for you, so just keep tinkering with your current approach